# Out of memory error in StAX

Tags: java, xml, stax

I am using the following simple StAX code to iterate through all the tags in XML. Size of
**input.xml > 100 MB**

```
XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("input.xml");
        XMLStreamReader xsr = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(in);

        xsr.next();
        while (xsr.hasNext()) {

            xsr.next();
            if(xsr.isStartElement() || xsr.isEndElement())
                 System.out.println(xsr.getLocalName());            
            }
        }
```

I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Please tell me how to get around this. I read that StAX takes care of huge XMLs well, but I am getting the same error as DOM Parsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the Heap size while running the JVM

```
-Xms    initial java heap size
-Xmx    maximum java heap size
-Xmn    the size of the heap for the young generation
```

Example:

```
bin/java.exe -Xmn100M -Xms500M -Xmx500M
```

Comment: I am using Eclipse Helios as IDE, should I make these changes in eclipse.ini or somewhere else? Also what is the diff between m and M, is it mB and MB?

Comment: M stands for MB. You have to add VM Arguments in Eclipse IDE (`Run Configuration --> Select Program to run --> Argument --> Add VM Arguments`)

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, that worked. But does that ensure that in future, if I use files of size more than 1 GB, the code will not run out of memory again. If yes, why?

Comment: No it will not insure. You have to add these VM arguments on every start of VM. These are Environment Variables. So cannot depend on the Program you are running.

Answer (score 1):

Increase the MaxHeap size of your Vm using the -Xmx parameter.

```
java -Xmx512m ....
```

Comment: That's fine, but in case the XML size increases the max size specified, it will fail again. Isn't there a robust solution/tweak in the code so that it handles all such cases?

Comment: DOM requires you to load the whole file into memory, SAX does stream processing and should only grow a distinct limit (which you probably hit). So it should be possible to process even files which are much larger.

Comment: In the menu "Run" -> "Run Configurations" In this dialog  you can specify them in the "Arguments" tab under "VM arguments".

Comment: In your previous comment, u said about "growing upto a distinct limit"- do you mean, stax is designed to use only a certain threshold amount of memory for any size of XML and upon crossing that limit, it will internally de-allocate some of the memory?

Comment: @Anand yes that the reason why there are two processing models.

Comment: in that case, can u please tell me what is the max memory that stax uses?

Comment: @Anand I'm sorry but it depends on several parameters I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia:
Traditionally, XML APIs are either:

```
tree based - the entire document is read into memory as a tree structure for random 
access by the calling application
event based - the application registers to receive events as entities are encountered 
within the source document.

StAX was designed as a median between these two opposites. In the StAX metaphor,
the  programmatic  entry point is a cursor that represents a point within the 
document. The application moves the cursor forward - 'pulling' the information from 
the parser as it needs. This is different from an event based API - such as SAX - 
which 'pushes' data to the application - requiring the application to maintain state 
between events as necessary to keep track of location within the document.
```

So for 100M and more - I preffer SAX - if it possible use instead StAX.

But I tryed your code with file size 2,6GB on JVM64. Without problem. So I suppose that problem not for size of file but for may be for data.